# How can I use axios inside an html (pug) file?

Tags: javascript, html, axios, pug

I am working on my first website. It needs to have a filter system for the products. I can get all the data I need, but can't seem to get the result from axios. The error message doesn't give me much clue as to how to fix it. It just says "Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern." Can anyone help? How can I either use axios in my html file or send the params data outside the file to somewhere I can use axios.

```
  script(src='https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js')
  script(src='filter.js')
  script(type='text/javascript' src='script.js')
  script.
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "275px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    async function applyFilter() {
      let temp = document.getElementById('flag_category');
      const category = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_color');
      const color = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_theme');
      const theme = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_flagType');
      const flagType = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_fabricType');
      const fabricType = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;

      if (color !== '') color = `color: '${color}',\n`;
      if (theme !== '') theme = `theme: '${theme}',\n`;
      if (flagType !== '') flagType = `flagType: '${flagType}',\n`;
      if (fabricType !== '') fabricType = `fabricType: '${fabricType}',\n`;
      if (category !== '') category = `category: '${category}',\n`;

      params = color + theme + flagType + fabricType + category;

      const flags = axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000api/v1/flags',
        data: { params }
      });
      console.log(flags);
      /*
        res.status(200).render('flagOverview', {
          title: 'Flags',
          products: flags
        });
        */
    };
```

Comment: please share all the code, it this HTML or are using another HTML precompiled like pug?

Comment: oops, forgot I was using pug. Yes, this is pug not html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

> url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000api/v1/flags',

It should be:

> url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/flags',

You missed a slash.

Comment: Oh my god. Of course it had to be something so simple. How could I have not notice it after looking at this for like 6 hours. Thanks so much.